# jQuery keypress get first word

Tags: jquery

In jQuery I get the value using following code:

```
$('#input_id').keypress(function(){ 
  var content= $(this).val(); alert(content);
});
```

In this case I type 'a' it alerts blank and I type 'ab' it alerts 'a'. Is any idea for when I type 'a' it should alert 'a' and when I type 'ab' it should alert 'ab'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use on("keyup" or on("input" since keypress is fired before the value is added to the field. You also use alert which blocks all further processing

```js
$('#input_id0').on("keypress",function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  console.log(content);
});
$('#input_id1').on("keyup",function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  console.log(content);
});
$('#input_id2').on("input", function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  console.log(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_id0" placeholder="keypress" /><br/>
<input id="input_id1" placeholder="keyup" /><br/>
<input id="input_id2" placeholder="input" /><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` instead of `keypress` function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input_id').keyup(function(){ 
   var content= $(this).val(); alert(content); 
  });
});
```

```css
a
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='input_id'>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're working with [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) event. Instead, you should use [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) to achieve your requirement.

```js
$('#input_id').keyup(function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  alert(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_id">
```